# INI file editing, Save format

Tags: powershell, format, ini, editing

So i have a working code. i just learned about this today but am wondering if there is a way to save the formatting. (found it on here btw).

```
$ini = Get-IniContent c:\temp\ini.ini 
$ini["posscreen"]["BitmapFile"] = "C:\Temp\FileC.bmp"  
$ini | Out-IniFile -FilePath c:\temp\ini2.ini
```

This is how it looks normally:

```
 [ShapePageFnt]
 Position=1.73 -2.76 -15.00
 Scale=0.35 0.36 0.38
 ZoneDepth=0
 StringLength=9600
 Font=VerdanaBold
 Color=0xFF000000
 Kerning=0.270000
 String=1/10
 StringAlignment=Left 

 [sgcArialBlack]
 FontFile=ArialBlack.png
 DataFile=ArialBlack.ftd
 StringLength=0
 StringStack=0
 StringAlignment=Center
 Kerning=0.25
 Color=0xFF00AAFF
 Position=0 0 -1000
 Dimension=1 1
 Scale=1 1 1
 String=

 [sgcXtraLabel]
 Position=-3.25 -5.61 -15.00
 Dimension=1.00 1.00
 Scale=0.33 0.33 0.33
 ZoneDepth=-101
 StringLength=20
 Font=VerdanaBold
 Color=0xFFFFFFFF
 String=Xtra Games
 StringAlignment=Center
```

After running the code:

```
[ShapePageFnt]
Position=1.73 -2.76 -15.00
Scale=0.35 0.36 0.38
ZoneDepth=0
StringLength=9600
Font=VerdanaBold
Color=0xFF000000
Kerning=0.270000
String=1/10
StringAlignment=Left 
[sgcArialBlack]
FontFile=ArialBlack.png
DataFile=ArialBlack.ftd
StringLength=0
StringStack=0
StringAlignment=Center
Kerning=0.25
Color=0xFF00AAFF
Position=0 0 -1000
Dimension=1 1
Scale=1 1 1
String=
[sgcXtraLabel]
Position=-3.25 -5.61 -15.00
Dimension=1.00 1.00
Scale=0.33 0.33 0.33
ZoneDepth=-101
StringLength=20
Font=VerdanaBold
Color=0xFFFFFFFF
String=Xtra Games
StringAlignment=Center
```

Any help would be appreciated.

** i tried -format and -table just for kicks and didn't do anything but pop up errors.**
Is there a /? for stuff in power shell to check if these conditions are even available?

End goal: to have the code ran and have it output the same way it inputs with the spaces. (the code replaces a set item in the .ini)

Comment: the help is in `Get-Help Cmdlet-Name -Full`. ///// to me, you are not clear about what the problem is ... are you wanting to add a delimiter line between each object?

Comment: Yes i want it to show like the "normal" but after i run the code not before. So yeah i guess add a line. Edited the question

Comment: thank you for the clarification. [*grin*] ///// it looks like you are using one of the `ini` modules. that is where the problem appears to arise ... have you attempted to get the author to help? if they are not responding, you will likely need to dig into the code yourself. ///// you likely otta document the module you are using ...

Comment: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/3.1.2                                         I will also email them

Comment: please, add that info to you Original Post so that others can find it without needing to dig for it. [*grin*] other than adding the line after the fact, i am out of ideas ... i'm back to lurking.

Comment: That cmdlet has a switch `-Pretty` which adds an extra linebreak between Sections. There's also a switch called `Loose` (strange name..) which adds spaces around the equal sign when writing the key = value. If you want that, use `$ini | Out-IniFile -FilePath c:\temp\ini2.ini -Pretty -Loose`

Comment: omg life saver. that works perfectly. So do you know why that wouldn't show up when i ran help against that? post that as a reply and ill mark it as an answer for credit :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but you didn't 'ping' met with `@`, so I didn't get notified. I have put my comment as answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the script and had a look at the parameters for the `Out-IniFile` function. I found two switch parameters there:

- `Pretty` which adds an extra linebreak between Sections
- `Loose` which adds spaces around the equal sign when writing the key = value

To use them, your command to write the ini file would be:

```
$ini | Out-IniFile -FilePath c:\temp\ini2.ini -Pretty -Loose
```

<sup>The author of that script forgot to add descriptions of the parameters in the comment-based help info, so that's why Get-Help didn't show it..</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment on the other answer, as I don't have enough reputation points.

[@Theo answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58474270/8176975) is correct; with the exception that the 2 parameters are indeed documented:
https://github.com/lipkau/PsIni/blob/master/PSIni/Functions/Out-IniFile.ps1#L98-L106

```
I ♥ PS> help Out-IniFile -Parameter pretty, loose

-Pretty [<SwitchParameter>]
    Writes the file as "pretty" as possible

    Adds an extra linebreak between Sections

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false


-Loose [<SwitchParameter>]
    Adds spaces around the equal sign when writing the key = value

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                False
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Also, the git repository of that module is https://github.com/lipkau/PsIni.
You can create issues there for missing functionality or general questions